# Prevent special characters but allow spaces with data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula in a cell's (F5) data validation to prevent special characters. But it also does not allow spaces. Does anyone know how I can tweak it to allow spaces as well as numbers and letters?

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(F5,ROW(INDIRECT("6:"&LEN(F5))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))
```

Comment: Perhaps just add a `space` to your list of allowed characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a space anywhere in the string of allowed characters -

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(F5,ROW(INDIRECT("6:"&LEN(F5))),1)," 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))
```

Comment: FIND is case sensitive; SEARCH is not. You only require either lower-case or upper-case alphabetic characters, not both.